# Is there a way to make certain, that the contents of a function labeled noexcept are not potentially throwing?

Tags: c++, exception

I would like a method to make certain, that any function labeled noexcept is only performing operations which are also noexcept.

I don't want to generate code calling std::terminate() nor do I want to swallow exceptions.

This could be done by some C++ way or some lint way.

Again: The motivation is to exploit possible compiler optimizations while not labeling such functions as noexcept, which actually can throw.

I read somewhere that one can pass a boolean expression to nexcept and I was thinking of something like this:

```
std::size_t myClass::method(void) noexcept(std::is_non_throw<methodImpl>::value)
{    return methodImpl();
}
```

Comment: No there is no way to check transitively (automatically). You could (rare exception) add a try/catch(const std::excption&) { } catch(...) { }. block (in debug builds) there.

Comment: Are you asking about compile-time verification, static analysis, runtime verification, or what?

Comment: In general case it's not static, so you cannot know that at compile time. Some linters may warn about it. Eg. C26447 warning from Microsoft compiler

Comment: To make certain, you'd need to inspect the code.  My hobby projects use a **naming convention** to discern throwing versus non-throwing functions, but that is fraught with peril if you also have code that does not abide by that naming convention.  Or if your dev team consists of more than one person (unless all devs are on the same page, and have compatible OCD).

Comment: @Eljay: What about functions like constructors and operators that you can't give names to?

Comment: @NicolBolas • Assumed to be non-throwing, unless **codedocs** documents otherwise.  Out of memory condition is a "welp, nothing can be done but terminate" situation.

Comment: Are you just looking for the [`noexcept` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept)? `std::size_t myClass::method(void) noexcept(noexcept(methodImpl())) { return methodImpl(); }`?

Comment: `-fno-exceptions`. But seriously, no :)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai -- I never worked for google!!

Comment: @Artyer doesnt that just defer the issue to `methodImpl` ?

Comment: Yeah, noexcept operator seems to be what OP is looking for. Caveat: this only works in C++17 and newer. Although this approach leaves some optimizations untapped - there are usually some functions that contain potentially throwing code but don't ever throw in reality due to invariants/preconditions.